# How to get total value of group of same json obj?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json, and it has all cities in Italy. Each city belongs to a Region.

Now what I need to do is to get all values `popolazione` for each region

eg. `regione: {codice: "03", nome: "Lombardia"}` and do a total count for each city to be able get the total of a region.

Json strcture:

```
{nome: "Dizzasco", codice: "013087", zona: {…}, regione: {…}, provincia: {…}, …}
nome: "Dizzasco"
codice: "013087"
zona: {codice: "1", nome: "Nord-ovest"}
regione: {codice: "03", nome: "Lombardia"}
provincia: {codice: "013", nome: "Como"}
sigla: "CO"
codiceCatastale: "D310"
cap: ["22020"]
popolazione: 565

nome: "Dobbiaco"
codice: "021028"
zona: {codice: "2", nome: "Nord-est"}
regione: {codice: "04", nome: "Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol"}
provincia: {codice: "021", nome: "Bolzano/Bozen"}
sigla: "BZ"
codiceCatastale: "D311"
cap: ["39034"]
popolazione: 3314

nome: "Domaso"
codice: "013089"
zona: {codice: "1", nome: "Nord-ovest"}
regione: {codice: "03", nome: "Lombardia"}
provincia: {codice: "013", nome: "Como"}
sigla: "CO"
codiceCatastale: "D329"
cap: ["22013"]
popolazione: 1455
```

Looking for:

**Total population in Lombardia is 2020**

And do that for every region.

This is what I got but I am pushing each city and each population per each city but I'm missing the logic to do a total for each region. Thought of doing a check if `inArray` or to do check for `city string name`

```
 var regioni = [];
 var popolazione = [];

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        for(var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
          var thisDataRegione = data[d];
          var thisDataRegioneNome = thisDataRegione["regione"].nome;
          regioni.push(thisDataRegioneNome["regione"].nome);           
          popolazione.push(data[d].popolazione);
      }
  });
```

Comment: firsty, replace all `var` with `let`

Comment: Why? That doesn't contribute anything to his question.

Comment: @Gabriel exactly, actually that suggestion might break users code if they follow it in case they don't use const too depending on the var type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand your json and code, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
let regioni = {};

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for(var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        let thisDataRegione = data[d];
        let thisDataRegioneNome = thisDataRegione["regione"].nome;

        // if we see this region name for the first time initialize the count
        // to zero, otherwise add the new population data
        if (regioni[thisDataRegioneNome] === undefined) regioni[thisDataRegioneNome] = 0;
        else regioni[thisDataRegioneNome] += data[d].popolazione;
    }
    // this should be an object that has the regions with the total count 
    // for example regioni["Lambardia"] == 2020
    // and so on
    console.log(regioni);
});
```

Comment: this will add each city population of each region, not the total for that region

Comment: I get Lombardia: NaN

Comment: can you supply me a link to the real json data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to maintain two different array. You can add this in an object like this, now you have region as key and total population as value.
if you want all the regions you can do `Object.keys(regionePopulation)`. This will give the array of regions.

```
var regionePopulation = {};
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        data.forEach((item) => regionePopulation[item.regione.name] = !regionePopulation[item.regione.name] ? item.popolazione : regionePopulation[item.regione.name] + item.popolazione)
console.log(regionePopulation)
  });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: popolazione is not defined

Comment: again with have Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @rob.m missed a semicolon, now it will work. Thank you

Comment: if I do console that array i get undefined: 59433744

Comment: @GauravSingh Provide a complete solution

Comment: @rob.m log it inside the callback as i did.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava did it. Thank you

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: and if I remove that { I get undefined: 59433744

Comment: I still get undefined: 59433744

Comment: try declaring the object as `var` instead of `let`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210696/discussion-between-gaurav-singh-and-rob-m).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is actually your data structure:

```
[
    {
        nome: "Dizzasco",
        codice: "013087",
        zona: {codice: "1", nome: "Nord-ovest"},
        regione: {codice: "03", nome: "Lombardia"},
        provincia: {codice: "013", nome: "Como"},
        sigla: "CO",
        codiceCatastale: "D310",
        cap: ["22020"],
        popolazione: 565,
    },
    ....
]
```

You're almost there. You need to *accumulate* the number, instead of storing each value in an array like you're doing now. See:

```js
var data=[
  {
    nome: "Dizzasco",
    codice: "013087",
    zona: {codice: "1", nome: "Nord-ovest"},
    regione: {codice: "03", nome: "Lombardia"},
    provincia: {codice: "013", nome: "Como"},
    sigla: "CO",
    codiceCatastale: "D310",
    cap: ["22020"],
    popolazione: 565,
  },
  {
    nome: "Dobbiaco",
    codice: "021028",
    zona: {codice: "2", nome: "Nord-est"},
    regione: {codice: "04", nome: "Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol"},
    provincia: {codice: "021", nome: "Bolzano/Bozen"},
    sigla: "BZ",
    codiceCatastale: "D311",
    cap: ["39034"],
    popolazione: 3314
  }
];

var populationByRegion={},
  totalPopulation=0;
for(var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
  var item=data[d],
    thisDataRegioneNome=item.regione.nome,
    population=item.popolazione;
  //If this is the first time we find this region, initialize the accumulator
  if(!populationByRegion.hasOwnProperty(thisDataRegioneNome)) populationByRegion[thisDataRegioneNome]=0;
  //Then just sum the population
  populationByRegion[thisDataRegioneNome]+=population;
  //You can also count the total among all the regions
  totalPopulation+=population;
}

console.log("Population by region",populationByRegion);
console.log("Total",totalPopulation);
```

Comment: hey I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popolazione' of undefined` on `population=thisDataRegione[d].popolazione;`

Comment: Sorry, it was just an idea, I hadn't tested it. Added a snippet.